# Java Calendar inconsistent results

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have searched for the answer to this, but cannot seem to find one.  Can someone explain why the following code does not give me the 1 of each month, but jumps to the 31 for some months?  It is for a report event that needs to determine the next month's date.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy"); 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone
    .getTimeZone( "America/Los_Angeles" ) );
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy"); 
Date date;
try
{
  date = (Date)formatter.parse("01-JUN-12");
  cal.setTime(date);
  //cal.set(2012, 05, 01);

  long now = new Date().getTime();
  int frequency = 1;

  System.out.println("Current calendar time=" + cal.getTime().toString()) ;

  while (cal.getTime().getTime() < now)
  {
      cal.add( Calendar.MONTH, frequency );
      System.out.println("In loop - current calendar time=" + cal.getTime().toString()) ;
  }
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is:

```
Current calendar time=Fri Jun 01 00:00:00 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Mon Oct 01 00:00:00 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Wed Oct 31 00:00:00 EDT 2012
```

Notice how it jumps to 31, then back to 1.  If I use Calendar.set() instead, the output is correct:

```
Current calendar time=Fri Jun 01 15:14:26 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Sun Jul 01 15:14:26 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Wed Aug 01 15:14:26 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Sat Sep 01 15:14:26 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Mon Oct 01 15:14:26 EDT 2012

In loop - current calendar time=Thu Nov 01 15:14:26 EDT 2012
```

This seems like it is either 1) A bug with the Calendar API, or 2) a lack of understanding of how the Calendar API works.  In either case, I just want the next month (same day), unless of course there is a problem with certain months and days.  But the above scenario is puzzling me.  This does not happen with any other day of the month, only with the 1st.

Comment: change library for date and time on joda time, in this library you don't find any bugs

Comment: Unfortunately I am bound to use the Calendar API, so switching is not an option for this project.

Comment: `Calendar` is arguably the most broken class in the JDK: It's virtually unusable. Internally it looks like it was written by a (bad) junior programmer. Use joda time. It's that simple. You should tell who ever is making you use `Calendar` that they should try working in a field *unrelated* to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a timezone issue. Replace your existing setup lines with the following, so that the Calendar and the Formatter are both using the same timezone:

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
```

and it all works fine:

```
Current calendar time=Fri Jun 01 08:00:00 BST 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Sun Jul 01 08:00:00 BST 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Wed Aug 01 08:00:00 BST 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Sat Sep 01 08:00:00 BST 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Mon Oct 01 08:00:00 BST 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Thu Nov 01 07:00:00 GMT 2012
```

You may want to replace the `toString()` calls with `formatter.format()` calls so that the output is in the right timezone too (it might look OK to you if you are in EDT, but I'm in the UK timezone, as you can see).

Comment: Great, this worked!  Forgot that we acquired this software from a start-up, and they were located in California!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of just `cal.add( Calendar.MONTH, frequency );`, try this:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, frequency);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Comment: That provided more consistent results, however it now shows the 2nd of each month:Current calendar time=Fri Jun 01 00:00:00 EDT 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Sat Jun 02 00:00:00 EDT 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Mon Jul 02 00:00:00 EDT 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Thu Aug 02 00:00:00 EDT 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Sun Sep 02 00:00:00 EDT 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Tue Oct 02 00:00:00 EDT 2012
In loop - current calendar time=Fri Nov 02 00:00:00 EDT 2012

Comment: At this point, I imagine it'd be something to do with timezones.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the time in the system default time zone. Use formatter to display it.

Set the same time zone for the formatter:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

And use it to display the time:

```
while (cal.getTime().getTime() < now) { 
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, frequency);
    System.out.println("In loop - current calendar time=" + formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I should have realized it was something simple!

Answer (score 0):

From Javadoc [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

add(f, delta) adds delta to field f. This is equivalent to calling set(f, get(f) + delta) with two adjustments:

- Add rule 1. The value of field f after the call minus the value of
  field f before the call is delta, modulo any overflow that has
  occurred in field f. Overflow occurs when a field value exceeds its
  range and, as a result, the next larger field is incremented or
  decremented and the field value is adjusted back into its range.
- Add rule 2. If a smaller field is expected to be invariant, but it is
  impossible for it to be equal to its prior value because of changes
  in its minimum or maximum after field f is changed or other
  constraints, such as time zone offset changes, then its value is
  adjusted to be as close as possible to its expected value. A smaller
  field represents a smaller unit of time. HOUR is a smaller field than
  DAY_OF_MONTH. No adjustment is made to smaller fields that are not
  expected to be invariant. The calendar system determines what fields
  are expected to be invariant.

In addition, unlike set(), add() forces an immediate recomputation of the calendar's milliseconds and all fields.

> Example: Consider a GregorianCalendar originally set to August 31, 1999. Calling add(Calendar.MONTH, 13) sets the calendar to September 30, 2000. Add rule 1 sets the MONTH field to September, since adding 13 months to August gives September of the next year. Since DAY_OF_MONTH cannot be 31 in September in a GregorianCalendar, add rule 2 sets the DAY_OF_MONTH to 30, the closest possible value. Although it is a smaller field, DAY_OF_WEEK is not adjusted by rule 2, since it is expected to change when the month changes in a GregorianCalendar.

So in your case considering the time that you have set if calendar API add month to `Jul` then it is possible that it is getting overflown more than a month so it is being adjusted back `Jul` Midnight